# Background color change is not applying while changing the width of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm learning html/css, and while making a page, I want to test if I could make the color of a button to change from red to green when the width is under 900px. After multiple tests, the other properties work fine (bold text, text color) but the background-color of the button doesn't seem to change at all, and I can't find why.

The HTML code is :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Landing EST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleaccueil.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleaccueilphone.css"> -->
</head>
<body>
    <header id="hautdepage">
            <img class="logoheader" src="/">
            <a href="nosactivites.html" class="texteheader">Nos activités</a>
            <a href="formulaire.html" class="texteheader">Formulaire</a>
            <a href="https://fr.linkedin.com"  target="_blank" class="texteheader">Nous connaître</a>
            <a href="mailto:xxx" class="texteheader"  target="_blank" >Nous contacter</a>
    </header>
    <div id="toutsaufheaderfooter" >
    <div class="presentation">
        <div class="textepresentation">
            <h1 class="titrepresentation">Qui sommes nous ?</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis atque consectetur ut amet laboriosam ratione fugit impedit velit, dolore in aliquid sint sit corporis ad sequi excepturi a tenetur molestiae eligendi ex delectus alias officia! Ratione dignissimos necessitatibus doloribus! Ipsa vel officiis optio, iure modi atque quo at aspernatur numquam.</p>
            <div class="boutonspresentation" >
                <a href="https://fr.linkedin.com" class="bouton1" target="_blank" >Faisons connaissance</a>
                <a href="mailto:xxx" class="bouton1" target="_blank" >Contactez-nous</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <iframe  src= "https://www.youtube.com/embed/weP6BLvfzG8" frameborder= "0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="deuxiemesalve">
        <div class="deuxiemesalveparagraphetitre">
            <div class="blocdeuxiemesalve" >
                <h2 class="h2deuxiemesalve">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
                <p class="textedeuxiemesalve">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse, tenetur quasi magnam fuga beatae eum voluptas repellat. Unde quam asperiores esse? Nesciunt praesentium enim aperiam culpa fugiat reprehenderit esse labore, nulla molestias. Hic debitis, officiis pariatur odit enim ut facere.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="blocdeuxiemesalve" >
                <h2 class="h2deuxiemesalve">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
                <p class="textedeuxiemesalve">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse, tenetur quasi magnam fuga beatae eum voluptas repellat. Unde quam asperiores esse? Nesciunt praesentium enim aperiam culpa fugiat reprehenderit esse labore, nulla molestias. Hic debitis, officiis pariatur odit enim ut facere.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="blocdeuxiemesalve" >
                <h2 class="h2deuxiemesalve">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
                <p class="textedeuxiemesalve">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse, tenetur quasi magnam fuga beatae eum voluptas repellat. Unde quam asperiores esse? Nesciunt praesentium enim aperiam culpa fugiat reprehenderit esse labore, nulla molestias. Hic debitis, officiis pariatur odit enim ut facere.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="troisiemesalve">
        <img class="imagedouble" src="images/howscrumwork.jpg">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptatum laudantium vel non quas eum aliquid ut quo incidunt aspernatur in aperiam, nulla, commodi vitae placeat. Magni similique cum omnis quae!</p>
        <img class="imagedouble" src="images/mecpostit.jpg">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptatum laudantium vel non quas eum aliquid ut quo incidunt aspernatur in aperiam, nulla, commodi vitae placeat. Magni similique cum omnis quae!</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="boitefooter">
            <div class="footerun">
                <p>ici on mettrais des liens vers les réseaux sociaux ou les mentions légales par exemple</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footerdeux">
                <a class="retourvershautdepage" href="#hautdepage" > Retour en haut de page </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

The 1st CSS code is :

```css
/* Reset CSS */
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* box-sizing: border-box; */
}

body{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
}
/*Ici je dis que toute la page sera en Lato sauf contradiction*/

/*Ici je me met le leins de la police Libre Franklin si besoin = font-family: 'Libre Franklin', sans-serif; */

header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.logoheader{
        min-width: 10%;
        min-height: 10%;
        max-width: 12%;
        max-height: 12%;
    margin : 1em
}
.texteheader{
    margin: 1em;
    color: black;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.retourvershautdepage{
    padding: 10px 30px; 
    background: rgb(192, 44, 44); 
    color: white; 
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    }
.retourvershautdepage:hover{
    background: rgb(196, 104, 17);
}

.retourverspageaccueil{
    padding: 10px 30px; 
    background: rgb(192, 44, 44); 
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    }
.retourverspageaccueil:hover{
        background: rgb(196, 104, 17);
}

footer{
    margin-top: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: darkblue;
    color: aliceblue;
    width: 100%;
}

.boitefooter{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:900px) {
    .retourvershautdepage{
        font-weight: bold;
    background: rgb(44, 192, 44); 
    }
.retourvershautdepage:hover{
    background: rgb(231, 217, 16);
}
    }
    .footerdeux{
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
```

The 2nd CSS is :

```css
.presentation{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 3em;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.presentation p{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.textepresentation{
    width: 30%;
    max-height: 15%;
    margin-right: 8em;
}

a.bouton1 {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 95); 
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
a.bouton1:hover {
    background: rgb(196, 17, 115);
    }

iframe{
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
}

.deuxiemesalveparagraphetitre{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.deuxiemesalve{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    margin-left: 7em;
    margin-right: 7em;
    text-align: center;
}

.h2deuxiemesalve{
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    margin-top: 3em;
}
.deuxiemesalveparagraphe{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.textedeuxiemesalve{
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
}

.troisiemesalve{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 5em;
    align-items: center;
}

.imagedouble{
    width: 20%;
    height: 15%;
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
}

.retourvershautdepage{
    padding: 10px 30px; 
    background: rgb(192, 44, 44); 
    color: white; 
    }


@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    body{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }
    
    #toutsaufheaderfooter{
        padding: 0 20px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .presentation{
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
    
    iframe{
        height: 248px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .textepresentation{
        width: 95%;
        padding: 15px 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .boutonspresentation{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .blocdeuxiemesalve{
        padding: 15px 0;
    }
    .deuxiemesalve{
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 15px;
    }

    .deuxiemesalveparagraphetitre{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-content: none;
        align-items: none;
    }
    .h2deuxiemesalve{
        margin: 0 0 15px 0;;
    }
    .textedeuxiemesalve{
        margin: 0;
    }
    .troisiemesalve{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .imagedouble{
        width: 60%;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your 2nd file define "retourvershautdepage backgroup color" again ,
You need to ensure @media is in the last of your css file , or it will be replaced by your 2nd file.

Comment: Could also foolproof this by using ```@media(min-width:900px) {...}``` to set color of desktop size, and ```@media(max-width:900px) {...}``` for the smaller size. If each viewport has their own specifications, you don't have to worry about having to overwrite anything.

Comment: @Lalalena Sure, you're right , I think this case is css class declare sequence problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you for the help ! I'm gonna test that rn

Comment: I deleted the "retourvershautdepage" section on the second css file and it worked, I feel dumn for not having thought of it ahah. Thanks again.